# Partially applied function from first-class function

Tags: scala

```
  val divide = (num: Double, den: Double) => {
  num / den
  }

  //type of pafv1 is () => (Double,Double) => Double
  val pafv1 = divide _


  //type of pafv2 is Double => Double
  val pafv2 = divide(_:Double,2)
```

Why type of `pafv1` is not `(Double,Double) => Double`? 
When `divide` is a simple method, type of `pafv1` is `(Double,Double) => Double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the explanation comes from [eta expansion](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion).

Scala makes getters and setters of `val`s, which means `divide` is in fact a method `def divide = (num: Double, den: Double) => { num / den }`

When you do `val pafv1 = divide _`, this expands it into the eta expanded version of divide, namely `() => (num: Double, den: Double) => { num / den }`

Why is it doing eta expansion? Because you are trying to use a method as a value (you are partially evaluating _, forcing the result to be a function value).

Answer (score 1):

That's weird... If you compile this piece of code:

```
class C {
  val f = (n: Double, d: Double) => n / d
  val pf = f _
}
```

with the `-print` flag, the desugared code is:

```
package <empty> {
  class C extends Object {
    private[this] val f: Function2 = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def f(): Function2 = C.this.f;
    private[this] val pf: Function0 = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def pf(): Function0 = C.this.pf;
    final <artifact> private[this] def $anonfun$f$1(n: Double, d: Double): Double = n./(d);
    final <artifact> private[this] def $anonfun$pf$1(): Function2 = C.this.f();
    def <init>(): C = {
      C.super.<init>();
      C.this.f = {
        ((n: Double, d: Double) => C.this.$anonfun$f$1(n, d))
      };
      C.this.pf = {
        (() => C.this.$anonfun$pf$1())
      };
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Some observations:

- The `val f` declaration is split into a `private this val f: Function2` and into an `<stable> <accessor> def f(): Function2`.
- The stable accessor method is wrapped into an anonymous function `$anonfun$pf$1()` that simply redirects all calls to `C.this.f()`.
- The `pf` eta-expands the parameterless `$anonfun$pf$1()` method into a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Function2`.

If I had to write down an equivalent piece of code that demonstrates "what actually happens", I'd probably write something like this:

```
class C2 {
  var f: Function2[Double, Double, Double] = _
  def fAccessor(): Function2[Double, Double, Double] = this.f

  f = (n: Double, d: Double) => n / d
  val pf = fAccessor _
}
```

Here you see that:

- `fAccessor` is a method without arguments that returns a `Function2`
- `pf` is eta-expansion of the accessor method `fAccessor`, which also takes zero arguments, and returns a `Function2`.

So, to conclude: for some weird reason, `f _` is the eta-expansion of the otherwise invisible accessor method. I think this should not compile at all, looks like an abstraction leak (some synthetic implementation dependent method symbols appearing out of nowhere).

---

What you might have wanted:

```
val pf: Double => Double => Double = n => f(n, _)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually "wrap" the function in a `case` expression:

```
val divide = (num: Double, den: Double) => num / den

val partialDivide: PartialFunction[(Double, Double), Double] = {
  case (num: Double, den: Double) if den != 0 => divide(num, den)
}

partialDivide(4, 2)
partialDivide(4, 0) // throws a `MatchError`
```

You can play around with this code [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/FTFWhbLpRzm5jMU03zCc6w).

You can find a very thorough explanation of the topic [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-use-partial-functions-in-scala-syntax-examples).

Answer (score 0):

From the [scala language specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-values) one can read:

If e is a parameterless method … , e _ represents the function of type () => T, which evaluates e when it is applied to the empty parameterlist ().

This is what we see happening.